# How do I handle a Controller that's not controlling a specific Model?

Tags: mvc

I've got a nice MVC set up going but my website requires some views that don't map directly to a model. Specifically I've got some generic Reports users need to run, and now I'm creating a utility for comparing some system configurations.

Right now the logic is crammed into a Reports Controller and I'm starting a Comparison Controller but this feels like a big abuse of the system. Both controllers use an assortment of different Models to pull data from, and they're only related based on *what the user is doing*. Reports are run from the Reports Controller and their views are all grouped together in the file system/URL structure.

Is this an acceptable use of the Controller paradigm? I can't think of a better way to structure my Controllers, and making a Controller for each model I'm using to make reports/ect doesn't seem like a good idea; I'd end up with one Controller/Model/View per report or comparison, vastly complicating the apparent structure of my site.

Comment: @RobertHarvey why fat models over controllers? Our last programmer largely abused Models and we've got a lot of icky code in them, I've been trying to minimize logic in Models.

Comment: Then add a Business Layer, between the model and the controllers, that is responsible for business logic (including your Comparison aspects).

Comment: I'm confused. The M and the C aren't typically my concern but since when are models and controllers supposed to be a 1 to 1 thing? If they were 1 to 1, why separate them in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Favor thin controllers; push as much of the data analysis as you can into a Business Logic Layer that coordinates data transfer between the controllers and the model, and use the controllers merely to coordinate the display of the data.

[The model is not necessarily a database. In MVC, the Model is both the data and the business logic needed to manipulate the data in the application.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Concepts)